# Recognize Text REST endpoint returns no results on success

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the recognizeText REST endpoint from javascript running locally on my dev machine. I can successfully call the endpoint, get the operation-location url for the result and send a GET request to that url.

The issue is the return from the operation-location url is 200 success (meaning the operation has completed and doesn't need more time), but the body of the result is always empty.

How can I get the extracted text from the response?

My code:

```
    var subscriptionKey: string = "my key";
    var endpoint: string = "https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/";

    var uriBase: string = endpoint + "/vision/v2.0/recognizeText?mode=Printed";

    const fetchData = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscriptionKey
      },
      body:
        '{"url": "https://www.bing.com/th/id/OIP.nZoyhANat4WNndv0jeoXFAHaLp?w=183&h=289&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.5&pid=1.7"}',
      method: "POST"
    };

    fetch(uriBase, fetchData).then(data => {
      var operationLocation = data.headers.get("Operation-Location");

      if (operationLocation) {
        const resultFetchData = {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscriptionKey
          },
          method: "GET"
        };

        setTimeout(function(operationLocation, resultFetchData) {
          fetch(operationLocation, resultFetchData).then(resultData => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(resultData, null, 2));
          });
        }, 10000);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: How's going ? Has your issue been solved?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your fetch request code block, try this :

```
fetch(uriBase, fetchData).then(data => {
    var operationLocation = data.headers.get("Operation-Location");

    if (operationLocation) {
      const resultFetchData = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscriptionKey
        },
        method: "GET"
      };

    setTimeout(()=> {
    fetch(operationLocation, resultFetchData).then(resultData => {
        return resultData.json();
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    });
    },10000);}
  });
```

Result :
[image]